# Is there a way to exclude certain numbers in a sequence?

Tags: summation, integer-sequence

For example, the sequence of triangular numbers can be expressed as $1/2 [n (n + 1)]$ with $n=1,2,3,4,...$ but is it possible to create a summation of everything remaining $(2,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,...)$? The problem I seem to have is the increasing amount of integers between each following triangular number.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[n_Integer] := Array[# (# + 1)/2 &, n, 1, Complement[Range[n (n + 1)/2], {##}] &]

f[5]
```

> {2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14}

```
Total @ f @ 5
```

> 85

You can get a closed form expression for the desired sum noting that (1) the sum of the first `m` triangular numbers is

```
Sum[n (n + 1)/2, {n, 1, m}]
```

> 1/6 m (1 + m) (2 + m)

and (2) the sum of integers up to `m(m+1)/2` is

```
m (m + 1)/2 (1 + m (m + 1)/2)/2
```

Taking the difference and `Simplify`ing:

```
m (m + 1)/2 (1 + m (m + 1)/2)/2 - Sum[ n (n + 1)/2, {n, 1, m}] // FullSimplify
```

we get

> 1/24 (-1 + m) m (1 + m) (2 + 3 m)

We can get the same result by generating a list of sums using `f` and using `FindSequenceFunction` on the list:

```
t[m_] := FindSequenceFunction[Total[f @ #] & /@ Range[100]][m]
t[m]
```

> 1/24 (-1 + m) (2 m + 5 m^2 + 3 m^3)

```
 t[5]
```

> 85

Comment: Truly excellent answer.

Comment: Thank you @KennyColnago.